# Bulk Insert into MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have some code that takes the first value in the dataframe and either inserts it into MySQL, or updates it (depending if the id is already in the DB or not).

However, I need to be able to create a loop to loop through all the values in the dataframe instead of just one. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my code for just one value:

```
class Example(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'sessionAttendances'
        _id = db.Column('_id', db.Unicode, primary_key=True)
        wondeID = db.Column('wondeID', db.Unicode)
        date = db.Column('date', db.Unicode)
        timezoneType = db.Column('timezoneType', db.Unicode)
        timezone = db.Column('timezone', db.Unicode)
        createdAt = db.Column('createdAt', db.Date)
        session = db.Column('session', db.Unicode)
        updatedAt = db.Column('updatedAt', db.Date)

        def __init__(self, _id, wondeID, date, timezoneType, timezone, createdAt, session, updatedAt):
            self._id = _id
            self.wondeID = wondeID
            self.date = date
            self.timezoneType = timezoneType
            self.timezone = timezone
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.session = session
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt

        @classmethod
        def add_or_update(cls, _id, wondeID, date, timezoneType, timezone, createdAt, session, updatedAt):
            entity = cls.query.filter_by(_id=sessionAttendance._id.iloc[0]).first()

            if not entity:
                entity = cls(sessionAttendance._id.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.wondeID.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.date.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezoneType.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezone.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.createdAt.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.session.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.updatedAt.iloc[0])
                db.session.add(entity)
                db.session.commit()
                print("Adding Record")
            else:
                entity.attendanceCode = 'late'
                db.session.commit()
                print("Updating Record")

            return entity

example = Example(sessionAttendance._id.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.wondeID.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.date.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezoneType.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezone.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.createdAt.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.session.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.updatedAt.iloc[0])
example.add_or_update(sessionAttendance._id.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.wondeID.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.date.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezoneType.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.timezone.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.createdAt.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.session.iloc[0], sessionAttendance.updatedAt.iloc[0])

examples = Example.query.all()
for ex in examples:
    print (ex.date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the MySQL method for bulk upsert is rather slow so maybe looping is your best option.

Here is how you'd do it using [`.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for idx,row in sessionAttendance.iterrows():
    example = Example(row._id, row.wondeID, row.date, row.timezoneType, 
                      row.timezone, row.createdAt, row.session, row.updatedAt)
    example.add_or_update(row._id, row.wondeID, row.date, row.timezoneType, 
                          row.timezone, row.createdAt, row.sessio, row.updatedAt)
```

Comment: Thank you @Vorsprung Dutch Technik. I will try that

Comment: @Pippa97: you're welcome. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung Dutch Tecknik, it worked great. The only problem is, is it's very slow. It takes 30 minutes to update 150,000 rows. I need it to be much faster. Is there a way of speeding it up? Is it how I'm committing it that is taking ages?

Comment: @Pippa97: you might try without the commit statements.

Comment: @Vosprung durch Technik: I took out the commit statements, and just put one after the loop at the end. I also took out the print statements. That saved 10 minutes, but it still needs to be much faster. Do you know how I could bulk update instead of going through each row individually?

Comment: Not bad for just removing those statements. I read some things about bulk update and that's slow, too, apparently. Do you have indexes on your database table? If so, you could remove those and add them back after the update; but not sure how much, if any, time that will save.

Comment: I have some indexes, but not many, not enough to make a diffference

Comment: I see. The thing is, writing to disk is slow. I don't think there's a way around this, unfortunately.